# Open embeddings of $\mathbb{A}^n$ into itself

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Suppose I have an open embedding $\mathbb{A}^n\hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^n$. Is this necessarily an isomorphism? Does this depend on the ground ring $\mathbb{k}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is an isomorphism.

Let $U$ be the open set, image of $\mathbb{A}^n$ and let $Z$ the complement. If $Z$ has a codimension one component, then there is a non-constant function $f$ such that $V(f)$ is contained in $Z$ and then $f$ is a non-trivial unit on $U$ which is impossible.

So codimension of $Z$ is more than one. Then the natural map $\Gamma(\mathbb{A}^n)\to\Gamma(U)$ is an isomorphism, which implies the original map must be an isomorphism.

Comment: Are you assuming anything about the base ring here? I thought that the claim about the natural map in your final paragraph required something like normality.

Comment: @HankScorpio Am not sure what you mean. Affine space is normal over any field.

Comment: Yes, but the OP says "[d]oes this depend on the ground ring" which makes me think that they're curious about the case when the ground ring is potentially not a field. Your answer doesn't say anything about what ground ring you're taking, but I guess you're only dealing with fields?

Comment: That's very helpful! Thanks a lot.